# how to use split twig template field content type in drupal 8?

Tags: twig

I need your help to solve the problem with split in twig.

- I want to separate my var `{{label}}` in an array,
  try using

  ```
  {% set array = label | split (" ")%}
  ```

> returns empty

- I want to separate a field node in an array,
  try using

  ```
  {% set array = content.field_fieldname | split (" ")%}
  ```

> returns empty

if someone helps me identify what I'm doing wrong, or I indicates a guide and / or tutorial that can solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{ label }} is in the template as an object, I solved get the string

```
{% set title = items[0]['content']['#context']["value"]|split(' ', 2) %}    

<h1>{{ title[0] }}</h1>
{{ title[1] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you check that the array is empty?

```
{% set label = 'this is a label'%}

{% set array = label | split (" ")%}

{% for elem in array %}
 {{loop.index}} - {{ elem}}
{% endfor %}
```

[Check this code online here](http://twigfiddle.com/e55shb)

Comment: Matteo, yes, that is, it works fine when I define the variable from the line of code, but when is a variable that comes from the field of the node does not work

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra could depends of the type of data, probably is not a string. try to dump the variable an update your question with the result. try with `{{ dump(label) }}`

Comment: I try, generates error loading the page, doesn't show the site :(

Comment: Use the technique to dump out the content variable.  Does that work?

Comment: hi @BrianVanegasParra is the dump requires many times probably because try to dump a big graph object so probably is not a string :) check in the doc or in the source code to inspect what kind of object is and then try do find a method tha rapresent it as a string.